# first duplicate and then change ID of duplicated data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records in table that I need to duplicate for some ID and to add different ID to that rows.
 Is it possible to be done with one query or I need to select first save that array of rows and then do update and insert?

The insert query for one row of table is:

```
insert into anag_competenze_medico (id_global_key, id_competenze_medico, id_anagrafica, valore_fisso, valore_percentuale, valore_fisso1, valore_percentuale1, valore_fisso2, valore_percentuale2, id_prestazione, id_user_invalidation, date_invalidation, id_user_changes, date_changes) values (-1, -1, -1, 0.00, 35.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, -1, -1, null, 1, '2011-07-19 00:00:00');
```

From it you can see structure of table.

In general I have doctors and their competences. When another doctor came to work on same possition I want just to run query and copy all competences for another doctor. So in general I need to duplicate that row but with ID of new doctor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390263/mysql-duplicate-certain-rows-using-sql?rq=1

Comment: i have added query for creation of one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
 INSERT INTO anag_competenze_medico (id_global_key, ...)
    (SELECT 'newID',....
    FROM anag_competenze_medico 
    WHERE id_global_key= 'oldID')
```

This copies the competencies of doctor with oldID to a new doctor (newID)