# mysql: duplicate some rows in a table changing info in the duplicated ones

Tags: php, mysql, sql, shell, csv

I've been working around [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187178/first-duplicate-and-then-change-id-of-duplicated-data-in-mysql), but I can not arrive to a suitable solution for what I have to do, which it is next:
I have this equivalences:

```
subject1 = subjectA
subject2 = subjectB
subject3 = subjectC
```

then I have a csv file with next data:

```
hour,subject,teacher,room
10-11,subject1,teacher1,room1
11-12,subject2,teacher2,room1
09-11,subject3,teacher3,room2
10-11,subject4,teacher2,room3
```

then I export this csv to mysql, so what I need to do is

```
duplicate row where subject like "subject1" and replace "subject1" by "subjectA";
```

and the same for subject2, subject3, when I say replace, I mean the text string "subject1" by the text string "subjectA".

I hope I could make myself clear, thanks a lot.

Comment: sounds easy, what have YOU tried?

Comment: "INSERT INTO `table 1` ('Activiy Id',Day,Hour,'Students Sets',Subject,Teachers,'Activity Tags',Room,Comments)(SELECT 'Subject' FROM `table 1` WHERE 'Subject'='Subject1')" but then I don't know how to follow on...

Comment: I've been thinking that I could also work on the csv file before to export it to mysql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't manage to make it the mysql way I did it the shell-script way, I upload the csv file through a web interface where there is a script behind the scene that send it to the mysql, so I did a preprocess that modify the csv file and then send it to the mysql-server, so this is the line(s) I added at the begining of the file:

```
<?php
$file=$_POST['file'];

system("sed -i -r 's/^(.*)(Original Subject)(.*)$/\\1\\2\\3\\n\\1New Subject\\3/g' $file");

.....
```

So I substitute the original line by 2 lines, the original one plus the new one...

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the columns where data doesn't change (hour, teacher, etc.) and the string you want to replace where data does change (subjectA).  Note that "subjectA" is surrounded by quotes.

```
INSERT INTO 
    `your_table` 
    (`hour`, `subject`, `teacher`, `room`) 
        SELECT 
            `hour`, 'subjectA', `teacher`, `room` 
        FROM 
            `your_table` 
        WHERE 
            `subject` = 'subject1'
```

Comment: Sorry, always says "Unknown column", let's say column_name=subject, oldname=sub_old, newname=sub_new, I've tried many combinations, I'm not clear what to put where...